# How is a "computer variable" defined mathematically?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Variables used in maths formulae are not the same that those of computing programs. Maths variables can be bound to a given value only once, and then keep that value.

On the other hand, a programming variable is "mutable". It is like a box with a name, to which we can change its value over time.

How can  a mutable programming variable be mathematically defined?

Comment: Say we want to graph the equation $y=x^2$. If we are binding a single value to $x$ that it keeps, which forces $y$ to have a single value it keeps, then where does the graph come from?

Comment: Wrong premise. A variable represents usually some amount that is... variable!

Comment: Here is something that should interest you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)

Comment: "... a variable is "mutable". It is like a box with a name..." Exactly ! A *variable* is a name. So, when you "work with" the syntax, you must use syntax rules for manipulating it. When you use it to "speak of" (semantics), you must give it a denotation (an object to refer to). When you write (in number theory) $2 \times x = x + x$, the $x$ can *denote* any number.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in $2 \times x = x + x$, $x$ is not a programming var. It is only a convenient way to say $2 \times 1 = 1 + 1$, $2 \times 2 = 2 +2$, $2 \times 3 = 3 +3$ ...

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla A variable in math is not variable once it gets a value.

Comment: @cibercitizen1 - Mathematics "invented" the use of *variables* long time ago before computer science. When you try to write $2 \times 1 = 1+1, 2 \times 2 = 2+2, 2 \times 3 = 3+3$, you are "demonstrating exactly what a *variable* is : an "ambiguous" name that stand for objects in your domain of discourse. Of course, the interplay between synatx and semantics dictate how to "use" them, i.e.(according to Wittgenstein) how to give them meaning.

Comment: According to a great philosopher and logician, Bertand Russell (1908) . "a variable is a symbol which is to have one of a certain set of values, without its being decided which one. It does not have first one value of a set and then another; it has at all times *some* value of the set, where, so long as we do not replace the variable by a constant, the 'some' remains unspecified."

Comment: @cibercitizen1, wrong again. In the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ the variable $n$ takes only the value 1?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Of course. It takes the same constant value for every term. And it is by no means a programming variable. It is only abbreviation of $a_1+a_2+a_3+...$ an expression without any kind of variable at all.

Comment: @cibercitizen1, $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots$ is a informal way of write the series. The $n$ in the $\sum$ is like the n in the loop FOR n=1 to M; sum=sum+a[n]; NEXT.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla. You are wrong. $a_1+a_2+...$ is not informal. $\sum$ is a shortand, and $n$ in it is "like" but it is not a programming variable. Please ask your math teacher.

Comment: @cibercitizen1, the expression with ... **is** informal and I can't ask to my math teacher because I'm senior lecturer (the exact translation is somewhat uncertain).

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Then, please study the [Haskell programming language](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) and you'll understand the difference among math variables and programming variables.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ $=$ $a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_{n-1}+a_n+a_{n+1}+... **are absolutely equivalent**. Hence the second is as informal or formal as the former one is.

Comment: @cibercitizen1, I'm no saying that math variables and programming variables are the same. My point is what your premise "Maths variables can be bound to a given value only once, and then keep that value." is **wrong**. And in your **new** ...-expression you have a **variable** $n$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Bertand Russell (1908) . "a variable is a symbol which is to have one of a certain set of values, without its being decided which one. **It does not have first one value of a set and then another; it has AT ALL TIMES some value of the set**, where, so long as we do not replace the variable by a constant, the 'some' remains unspecified." Got it now? Or maybe Russell is also wrong!

Answer (score 5):

From the **EDITOR'S NOTES** to David Hilbert & Wilhelm Ackermann, *Principles of Mathematical Logic* (2nd ed : 1937; english transl : 1950), page 168 :

> The distinction between variables and constants [...] is sometimes difficult to grasp clearly. It is not always understood that a constant, like a variable, is a symbol,
> a linguistic expression, but with the important distinction that a constant has a fixed designation, which remains unaltered throughout the discussion in which the constant appears; whereas a variable designates ambiguously, so to speak, assuming anyone
> of a range of values. It would, however, be a grave error to suppose that the distinction between variables and constants reflects a corresponding distinction in the domain of objects to which the variables and constants alike refer. Thus to assert with reference, say, to real number theory that the variables "$x$" and "$y$" designate variable numbers, whereas such constants as "$2$" and "$\pi$" designate constant numbers, would be nonsense; or at least there is no known intelligible theory which could accommodate so odd a notion as that of a variable number.

In mathematical logic, *variables* are mainly used with *quantifiers*.

In order to compare with computer science, we can see Zohar Manna, *Mathematical theory of computation* (1974), where the language of predicate calculus [page 77-on] is used for the description of *programs*.

We have [page 82] the usual definition of *well-formed formula* :

> (c) If $v_i$ is a variable and $A$ is a wff, then $\forall v_i A$ and $\exists v_i A$ are wffs.

Then he use *variables* to formalize flowchart programs [page 161] :

> We distinguish among three types of variables (grouped as three vectors): (1) an input
> vector $\overline{x} = (x_l, x_2,. . . , x_a)$, which consists of the given input values and therefore never changes during computation; (2) a program vector $\overline{y} = (y_1, y_2, ..., y_b)$, which is used as temporary storage during computation; and (3) an output vector $\overline{z} = (z_1, z_2, ... z_c)$, which yields the output values whe computation terminates.

Finally, the assignment function is introduced [page 164] :

> Note that $(y_1, y_2) \leftarrow (0, x_1)$ means that $y_1$ is replaced by $0$ and $y_2$ is replaced by $x_1$ [...]. In general, we shall use the notation $(y_1, y_2, ..., y_n) \leftarrow (g_1(\overline{x}, \overline{y}), ... g_n(\overline{x}, \overline{y}))$ to indicate that the variables $y_i, 1 \le i \le n$, are replaced by $g_i(\overline{x}, \overline{y})$ *simultaneously*; that is, *all* the $g_i$'s are evaluated before any $y_i$ is changed. For example, if $y_1 = 1$ and $y_2 = 2$, the assignment $(y_1, y_2) \leftarrow (y_1 + 1, y_1 + y_2)$ yields $y_2 = 3$, not $y_2 = 4$.

In *computer languages*, the instruction $x=x+1$ (if allowed) is not a numerical identity; there are **no** reasonable meanings of the concept "number" that may make sense of a statement like : "a number is equal to itself plus $1$".

In the context of computer languages, when we use the instruction

> $x_1 \leftarrow x_1 + 1$

the symbol $x_1$ is not a *variable*: it is a *constant*.

It is the name of a storage location (memory array or register), like the square on the tape of a Turing machine, and the simple statement above is a "complex" instruction specifiying the following operation :

> *i)* read the content of the storage location ("cell") $x_1$, (say $n$);
>
> *ii)* add $1$ to that number;
>
> *iii)* erase the content of the cell $x_1$;
>
> *iv)* write the number $n+1$ into the cell $x_1$.

During the context of the execution of the program, the name $x_1$ will not change its denotation (the "cell").

The above process can be described as follows: we have a box with six eggs inside and we pull out the eggs from the box. Then we add a new egg and finally we put the seven eggs in the box :

> > the box does not change, his content has changed.

Comment: Very well documented and an interesting read. But I do not understand the definition of well-formed formula, nor its application to the ensuing argumentation. Is it the fact that "variables" are "something that appears in wffs"? Also, when Mana requires that variables be assigned simultaneously, he is proposing an ideal model of computation, right?

Comment: @logc - About wff, Manna use the standard definition of math log textbooks: I've copied only the passage related to *variables*. He introduces *Terms*: "Each individual constant $a_i$ and each individual variable $x_i$ is a term"; then *atomic formulas* like : "if $t_1$ and $t_2$ are terms, then $(t_1 = t_2)$ is an atf. Finally, he introduces well-formed formulas (wffs) built up with *connectives* ($\lnot A$, $A \lor B$) and *quantifiers* ($\forall$ and $\exists$), and here we have : "If $v_i$ is a variable and $A$ is a wff, then $\forall v_i(A)$ and ..." is a wff". 1/2

Comment: @logc - And yes, the "ideal model" is used for the purpose of "describe methods for verifying computer programs. [...] In order to discuss programs and their correctness we must specify a programming language. We shall consider flowchart programs without arrays". 2/2

Answer (score 4):

Apparently what you are after is the fact that we cannot have an equality $x=x+1$ in math, whereas assignments $x=x+1$ are ubiquitous in programs. The closest thing to this "we" have is a variable substitution maybe. Of course, math variables are also "local" in some sense, i.e. I might write "let $p$ be an even integer" and after finishing the corresponding argument start a new one with "let $p$ be any prime" - and the reader should not assume that both restrictions hold (which would force $p=2$).
But *within* an argument, $p$ is unchanged - though it perhaps doesn't even have a fixed value at all: If I let $p$ be an even integer, it is an *arbitrary* even integer; it could be $42$ or $666$, but neither *is* it any of these possibilities specifically (except e.g. during a refined case-distinction in a sub-argument) nor does it therefore ever change its "value".

But what we really do *not* have is the temporal aspect of running computer programs *per se*. Whenever we have the urge to emulate this, we use sequences $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ or functions $f(t)$ where you may perhaps interpret $x_n$ as the "value of $x$ after $n$ steps" or $f(t)$ as the "value of $f$ at time $t$"; but keep in mind that we may deprive you of this interpretation by using other index sets than $\mathbb N$ / other domains than $\mathbb R$. Specifically - and this may provoke some "actual vs. potential infinity" debates - one should consider such a sequence (or function) as given as a complete object - even if a recursive definition suggests that we compute (or even define) it step by step; if one didn't do so, transcending to larger infinities than countable (or in fact getting there in the first place) would be hindered.

A whole different story are random variables. The programmer's idea of invoking `rand()` is very different form the probability theorists idea of random variables being measurable functions on suitable measure spaces. While a computer random variable assumes values again and again, a math random variable never assumes a value, it only has a probability to assume a value within certain sets.

Comment: If I understand well your explanation, I agree with you that the "correct" meaning of $x = x+1$ in computer programming is **not** an "identity". If I remember well, someone prefer to avoid this sloppiness and write instead $x := x+1$, that is "let we *assign* to x ..." You are right also in pointing at "context"; often we omit the context, but in $2 \times x = x+x$ it is "strictly forbidden" to assign to the first $x$ the value $1$ and to the second one the value $2$, because in the "context" of the entire identity the $x$ is universally quantified.

Comment: Lazy evaluation gives us a means of simulating theses (potentially ) infinite sequences. This type of data structure is called a stream.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that *assignment* of "computer variables" happens in some programming languages - namely, those of the imperative programming paradigm, such as C or Java. In other programming paradigms this is explicitly forbidden - e.g., functional or logic programming.

In Haskell or Prolog, a statement of the form

```
x = x + 1
```

will lead to a compiler error. Variables are immutable, just like those in mathematics. This leads naturally to an emphasis in *functions* that transform input into output, not in *data* that is rewritten from input into output. (And many more advantages in the sense of approaching programming to mathematics, such as *functions that return always the same output given the same input*).

Probably the confusion arises from using the same words in both fields for different things. A variable in programming, as you have noted, is "a box with a name". More formally, it is a reference to an address in memory. What this part of memory holds, we cannot know from the variable - we can know some things, such as its length if it is a typed variable, but not the actual value unless we look at the memory contents.

"Computer variables" could be compared to an *index within a vector or matrix*. If we regard the memory as a vector $m$, then a variable is its $i$-th element

$$
\overrightarrow{m}_{i}, 0 < i < \left| \overrightarrow{m} \right|
$$

This supposes that all variables need precisely one memory element to be held. This is probably not true, since a double-precision number requires twice the memory as a float. So, a computer variable could be compared to a *range of elements within a vector*.

$$
[\overrightarrow{m}_{i}, \overrightarrow{m}_{j}] , 0 < i < j < \left| \overrightarrow{m} \right|
$$

You could imagine different states of memory as different vectors $\overrightarrow{m}'$, $\overrightarrow{m}''$ ... Indexing those different vectors at the same indices $i$, $j$ (hence the same "computer variable") would yield different elements each time.

Comment: Thanks - I apologize for my "old style" computer science examples, but when I've studied "some" computer scince at university, Manna's textbook was *pretty new* ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - No need for apologies, my math is super rusty quite some years after college.  You are right that Haskell is a "newcomer" from the early '90s, but [Prolog was already around](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) when Manna published that book. :)